# PHP & MYSQL -- how to dispaly "Already booked please select another date" message

Tags: php

I want to display this message "Already booked - please select another date" If two clients select the same product (pg_no)and date (Date). UNIQUE CONSTRAINT

```
<?php
//connecting string
include("dbconnect.php");

//assigning
$name=$_REQUEST['Name'];
$tele=$_REQUEST['Tele'];
$city=$_REQUEST['City'];

// UNIQUE CONSTRAINT   
$pg_no=$_REQUEST['pg_no']; //product
$date=$_REQUEST['Date'];       //date

//checking if pg_no and Date are same  
$check = mysqli_query($db_connect,"SELECT * FROM lstclient WHERE pg_no='{$pg_no}', Date='{$date}'");

{
    echo "Already booked please select another date<br/>";
}
//if not the insert data
else
{
    $query = mysqli_query($db_connect,"INSERT  INTO  lstclient(pg_no,Name,Tele,City,Date) VALUES('$pg_no','$name','$tele','$city','$date')") or die(mysql_error());
}

// link closing
mysqli_close($db_connect);

// messaging  
if($query)
{
    header("location:index.php?note=failed");
}
else
{
    header("location:index.php?note=success");
}
?>
```

Comment: what should i add in HTML page

Comment: Please at least post valid code - `INSERTINTOlstclient` is not correct.

Comment: INSERT INTO lstclient

Comment: I want to display this message "Already booked - please select another date" If two clients select the same product (pg_no)and date (Date).  UNIQUE CONSTRAINT

Comment: You are not clarifying your question. Do the answers below make sense, or are you trying to do something different? I understand what you want - the end goal, but your not making your problem very clear, what is preventing from reaching your end goal.

Comment: Hi Samuel, thanks for your help
I have two issues and both are linked.  First, "already booked - please select another date" is not appearing, if two clients select the same product (pg_no) and date (Date).  These fields are  UNIQUE CONSTRAINT.  

Second, when data is inserted or submitted localhost shows complete address 
http://localhost/lstcomp/ index.php?note=submitted. But when  it fails the localhost shows only : http://localhost/lstcomp/
I hope you have much better idea now.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To view the message on your HTML page, based on the code you have provided, you just need to set a `$_GET` var:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['note']))
{
    if($_GET['note'] == 'failed';)
    {
        $note = "Those dates have already been booked.";
    }
    else if($_GET['note'] == 'success')
    {
        $note = "You have been booked!";
    }
}
else
{
    $note = "";
}
?>

<div class="message">
    <p class="alert">
        <?php
            if ($note != "")
            {
                echo $note;
            }
        ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

That would check for a `note` parameter in your url and set it to `$note` then output it in your HTML.

You don't need to add anything to the database, you can save the request and log it so you can view which dates are the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

You have two simple options here.

**Option 1 - Assign the message to a variable**

Instead of echoing your error message, store it in a variable which has a default value (for example, "Success"). Then, where you do the final `header()` part of your code, return this variable as note:

```
$my_str = "Already booked please select another date<br/>";

...

header("location:index.php?note=$my_str");
```

Then on the HTML side, you just need to print the value of `$_GET['note']`.

**Option 2 - See Samuel Fonseca's answer**

He beat me to it!